# редактируемый аккордеон

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю меню-выпадающий список. Должна быть возможность редактирования текста поля меню (его названия).

```
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
    <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox"  name ="group-1" id="group-1" checked>
        <label for="group-1" id="t1" >Group 1</label>
```

Если добавить свойство `contenteditable` для `label`, то меню не разворачивается. Какими способами можно реализовать нужный функционал?

весь код:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
      var accordionsMenu = $('.cd-accordion-menu');
      if (accordionsMenu.length > 0) {
        accordionsMenu.each(function() {
            var accordion = $(this);
            accordion.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
                (checkbox.prop('checked')) ?
                checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:none;').slideDown(300):
                  checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:block;').slideUp(300);
              }
            });
        });
    }
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Jaldi", sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #a0f6aa;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  color: #a0b0f6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2em auto 0;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  color: #507b55;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
  }
}

input {
  font-family: "Jaldi", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.cd-accordion-menu {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  background: #4d5158;
  margin: 4em auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 40px #70ac76;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul {
  display: none;
}

.cd-accordion-menu li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cd-accordion-menu label,
.cd-accordion-menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 18px 18px 64px;
  background: #4d5158;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #555960;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu label:hover,
.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu a:hover {
  background: #52565d;
}

.cd-accordion-menu label::before,
.cd-accordion-menu label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu a::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.cd-accordion-menu label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cd-accordion-menu label::before,
.cd-accordion-menu label::after {
  background-image: url(../img/cd-icons.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cd-accordion-menu label::before {
  left: 18px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}

.cd-accordion-menu label::after {
  left: 41px;
  background-position: -16px 0;
}

.cd-accordion-menu a::after {
  left: 36px;
  left: 6px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  background-position: -62px 0;
}

.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked+label+ul,
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:nth-of-type(n)+ul {
  display: block;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul a {
  background: #35383d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #41444a;
  padding-left: 82px;
}

.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu ul label:hover,
.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu ul a:hover {
  background: #3c3f45;
}

.cd-accordion-menu>li:last-of-type>label,
.cd-accordion-menu>li:last-of-type>a,
.cd-accordion-menu>li>ul>li:last-of-type label,
.cd-accordion-menu>li>ul>li:last-of-type a {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul label::before {
  left: 36px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
  left: 59px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul a {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::before {
  left: 54px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul a::after {
  left: 77px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a {
  padding-left: 118px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::before {
  left: 72px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a::after {
  left: 95px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .cd-accordion-menu label,
  .cd-accordion-menu a {
    padding: 24px 24px 24px 52px;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu label::before {
    left: 24px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu label::after {
    left: 53px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul a {
    padding-left: 76px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label::before {
    left: 48px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
    left: 77px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul a {
    padding-left: 100px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::before {
    left: 72px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul a::after {
    left: 11px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a {
    padding-left: 124px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::before {
    left: 96px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a::after {
    left: 125px;
  }
}

.cd-accordion-menu.animated label::before {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-1" id="group-1" checked>
    <label for="group-1" id="t1">Group 1</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1">
        <label for="sub-group-1">Sub Group 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Text</a></li>
          <li><a>Text</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name="group-2" id="group-2">
    <label for="group-2">Group 2</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Text</a></li>
      <li><a>Text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Приведите весь код, пожалуйста.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил

Comment: У вас в примере кода ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.